# PHP でエラー Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "else", expecting end of file

Tags: php

PHPでユーザー管理のサイトを作成していますが、最後の完了サイトでエラーになります。
エラー内容は以下の通りで77行目を指摘しています。

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "else", expecting end of file
```

構文エラーと、カッコを閉じていない際に出るエラーの2つが77行目で出ていると思いますが、elseの前後を確認しても、問題が発見できませんでした。
また、カッコの閉じ忘れも発見できませんでした。
原因調査に協力いただければと存じます。
77行目は
else {
です。
ソースコードを添付いたします。

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST") {
        header("location: http://localhost/Portfolio/user_create_commit.php");
        exit;
        }

    try{
        require_once('db_connect.php');
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "次がエラーの内容です。;" .$e->getMessage();
            }

    function escape($val)
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
    }

    require_once('password_hash.php'); 

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=ja>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ユーザーメンテナンス（完了）</title>
        <meta name="description" content="ユーザーの修正画面">
        <!--リセットcss-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
        <!--css-->
        <link href="css/user_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--レスポンシブ対応-->
        <meta name="viwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--Googleフォント-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sawarabi+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Mincho:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ユーザーメンテナンス（完了）</h1>
        <?php
            $sql=$pdo->prepare('insert into user_table(id,last_name,first_name,last_name_kana,first_name_kana,user,password) values (null,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
                if(empty($_POST['sei']) || empty($_POST['mei']) || empty($_POST['sei_kana']) || empty($_POST['mei_kana']) || empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password2']))
                    {
                        echo '未入力の項目があります。';
                    }
                    else if(!preg_match('/\A[ァ-ヴー]+\z/u', $_POST['sei_kana']) || !preg_match('/\A[ァ-ヴー]+\z/u', $_POST['mei_kana']))
                        {
                             echo 'カナ名は全角カナで入力してください。';
                        }
                        else if(!preg_match('/\A[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]+\z/u', $_POST['user']))
                            {
                                echo 'ユーザーは半角英数字記号で入力します';
                            }
                            else if(!preg_match('/\A[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{10,}\z/u', $_POST['password']))
                                {
                                    echo 'パスワードは半角英数字記号10文字以上で入力します。';
                                }
                                else if(!preg_match('/\A[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{10,}\z/u', $_POST['password2']))
                                    {
                                        echo 'パスワードは半角英数字記号10文字以上で入力します。';
                                    }
                                    else if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password2'])
                                        {
                                            echo '2つのパスワードが一致してません。';
                                        }
                                        else if($sql->execute(
                                                [escape($_POST['sei']),
                                                escape($_POST['mei']),
                                                escape($_POST['sei_kana']),
                                                escape($_POST['mei_kana']),
                                                escape($_POST['user']),
                                                htmlspecialchars($pass,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')]));
                                            {
                                                echo '<p class="msg">','登録に成功しました。','<p>';
                                            }   
                                            else {
                                                        echo '<P class="msg">','登録に失敗しました。','</p>';
                                                    }
        ?>
        <p class=return><a href="user_table.php">ユーザーメンテナンスへ戻る</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

67-73行目の `if` 文で、末尾の `;` が余計だと思います。

**元のコード(抜粋):**

```php
else if($sql->execute(
    // ...
    htmlspecialchars($pass,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')])); // <-- ";" が余計
{
```

**修正後:**

```
else if($sql->execute(
    [escape($_POST['sei']),
    escape($_POST['mei']),
    escape($_POST['sei_kana']),
    escape($_POST['mei_kana']),
    escape($_POST['user']),
    htmlspecialchars($pass,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')]))
{
    echo '<p class="msg">','登録に成功しました。','<p>';
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。解決しました。